# Flutter web: Unable to zoom in zoom out page using ctrl key + mouse wheel

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to zoom in zoom out on flutter web but its not working with ctrl key + mouse wheel.
Is there any script which we can use in index.html or is there any flutter widget to solve this issue
I tried it with interactive widget
how can we enable this on flutter web?

Comment: Hmm good question. I guess flutter disables it for some reason. Note that `Ctrl` + `-` and `Ctrl` + `+` to zoom out and in does work